# Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException Ao fazer um POST

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, xamarin-forms

Estou tendo problema ao fazer o post na minha API o meu app até cadastra o objeto mas depois ele trava o aplicativo e fecha com esse erro de execção:

**Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: {. Path '', line 1, position 1.**

```
   public async Task<int> AddFrutas(Fruta fruta)
            {
                HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
                var data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(fruta);
                var content = new StringContent(data, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                var response = await client.PostAsync("http://nivelamento.gopagoda.io/api/frutas", content);

                var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<int>(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
                return result;

            }
```

Comment: Pode adicionar o valor de data serializado, por gentilezA?

Comment: "nome": "Banana",
    "vitamina": "E", @Aline

Comment: E quanto ao valor de response?

Comment: @Aline, consegui resolver já coloquei a resposta a baixo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema estava na hora de Deserializar o objeto, mudei para dynamic e resolvou meu problema.

```
public async Task<dynamic> AddFrutas(Fruta fruta)
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    var data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(fruta);
    var content = new StringContent(data, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

    var response = await client.PostAsync("http://nivelamento.gopagoda.io/api/frutas", content);

    var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
    return result;

}
```

Comment: Rodrigo, é uma boa prática adicionar uma verificação do "HttpStatusCode" para garantir que seu Request foi "OK" para deserialização de valores.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica @EltonAlmeidaVieira.